# just_audio stops playing after first bytes are played but sourcelength is null

Tags: flutter, audio, audio-streaming, just-audio

When I start playing request is called with start=null and end=null.
When it is finished playing these bytes, there is no additional call to request.

I've been struggling with this for a few days now, with every different implementation getting a different error. So all tips welcome. I stream from the OpenAI TTS endpoint.

```
class MyCustomSource extends StreamAudioSource {
  List<int> bytes = [];
  Stream<List<int>> byteStream;

  MyCustomSource(this.byteStream) {
    byteStream.listen((event) {
      this.bytes.addAll(event);
    });
    print("Added ${bytes.length} bytes to List<int>");
  }

  @override
  Future<StreamAudioResponse> request([int? start, int? end]) async {
    print("Request called with start: $start and end: $end");
    print("Bytes.lenght: ${bytes.length}");

    start??=0;
    end??=bytes.length;
    return StreamAudioResponse(
      rangeRequestsSupported: true,
      sourceLength:  null, // this should indicate that we don't know the full lenght of the stream
      contentLength: end-start,
      offset: start,
      stream:  Stream.value(bytes.sublist(start, end)),
      contentType: 'audio/mpeg',
    );
  }
}
```